# Chef-server 12.1.0 backup and restore gives me 401

Tags: backup, chef-server, http-error-401.2, manage

I have a chef server with opscode-manage and I would like to backup everything (config, db etc..) for the restore on an a new server

I have backed-up and gunziped

> - the entire postresql (dump)
> - /etc/opscode
> - /var/opt/opscode

On the new server I have extracted and rsync -a everthing and done a reconfigure.

I checked in the DB and all the orgs and users are there.

Chef manage UI shows UP but I get 401 when I try to login. When I try (to test) to reset the password the password page after clicking submit give me a 401 page

Can someone help debug this ? Which log is going to be helpful here ? postres, ngix and rabbitmq are all without errors